# Plotting y axis tick in Visualforce Radar Chart

Tags: visualforce-charting

Here is my chart

[image]

I want the plotting start by even number such as 0,2,4,6,8,10 instead of 0 to 10.I tried steps or margin but it does not work.

```
<apex:axis type="Radial" position="radial"  steps="2" minimum="0" maximum="10">
    <apex:chartLabel />
</apex:axis>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Steps will only work when axis type is Numeric and margin will only for Gauge type. In your case it is Radial that's why it is not working.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this?